# Google maps grid lines appearing

Tags: google-maps

[image]For some unknown reason grid lines are appearing on my map in all browsers. I have looked for a solution but nothing seems to fix it. Every solution I have found says you need to set your browsers to compatibility mode.

```
function Initialize() {
            var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688,-74.004142);
            var options = {
                zoom: 8,
                scrollwheel: false,
                center: centerPosition,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                }
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: centerPosition,
                map: map![enter image description here][2]
            });
        };
```

Comment: It is a CSS problem. Your CSS is being applied to the map tiles (images).

Comment: Thanks, if you post this as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a CSS problem. Your CSS is being applied to the map tiles (images).

Comment: Can you describe the fix in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where lines appeared over the Google Map.  Upon careful inspection, I found that the problem only reproduced in Chrome.  There is an answer given in a similar question:

[Google Maps random vertical line in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997181)

The short version is that when you zoom in and out in Chrome, a bug in the browser causes lines to appear.  Hopefully, this bug will be fixed soon and this answer will be obsolete!

Also, in the case that the place on the map is Hawai'i, there is a vertical line between the islands of O'ahu and Moloka'i and a horizontal line between the islands of O'ahu and Kaua'i.  These lines appear to be part of the map, for some reason, and are not the result of a browser defect.