# Google Maps random vertical line in Chrome

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am implementing google maps on my website and I just started noticing this line appearing. It only happens in Chrome (Windows) and no matter how far I step back in my code I can't seem to make it disappear. As you zoom out, the line randomly renders elsewhere in the viewport, generally on the right side.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

[image: line on map]
[image: line on map]

Here is the CSS I have applied to the map_canvas:

```
  #map_canvas img {
      max-width: none!important;
   }
   #map_canvas {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
   }
   /** Make the map responsive to the container **/
   .map-container {
      height: 0;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 80%;
      margin-right: -3%; /*compensation for margin0 on span9*/

   }
```

And here is the basic HTML structure of the map canvas item.

```
  <div class="span9">
     <div class="map-container"> <!-- container needed for responsiveness -->
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div class="hidden-phone">
           <ul>
              <li onclick="toggle()">Restrooms</li>
              <li onclick="toggle()">Handicap Access</li>
           </ul>
        </div>        
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You removed map controls on purpose?

Comment: It's just a small screen shot of the affected area at different zoom levels. Zoom controls are present

Comment: Probably a css problem (being applied to the tiles).  Need more information to know for sure.

Comment: Same bug here http://www.dev.erosion.geographica.gs. Chrome OSX (Versión 34.0.1847.116). OSX 10.9.2. I'm using a LeafLet Plugin in order to show a Google Layer.

Comment: Same bug mentioned here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JLle91SnBug

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem on chrome, i switched to the version 3.14 and this solved the problem
if you include the script for google like this it should solve the problem

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: While this solved the vertical line issue, I noticed that it makes zooming in and out of the map function much slower. Did anyone else experience this?

Comment: nope, i havent seen such a problem but maybe you can try **3.15** maybe that solves the speed problem that you mentioned

Comment: @btargac: it seems that the issue was introduced in 3.15, so 3.14 is currently the last version without the bug.

Comment: whether it's loaded with ?v=3.14 or ?v=3.15 or no parameter at all, I see no difference in the code or the result. I always get the white lines, also horizontally, in Chrome.

Comment: could you share the link? maybe i can see a different problem ? @Ralf

Comment: Hi @btargac, thanks, sure, here's a link to a test site: http://web1470.login-11.loginserver.ch/
The live site is here: http://www.burgdorf-info.ch/ - no problem there (white lines appear briefly while zooming, but then quickly disappear). The issue only appeared after I updated the Geomap module on the test site.

Comment: Hi, just checked your source code of the test page, i realised that your way of calling the script is different than what is mentioned in the solution, could you try replacing line 87 with this kind of calling ? @Ralf

your code is: src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
how it should be :  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&sensor=true"

Comment: Thanks for checking. Sorry, I had not changed the code on that site. But as I said, it really doesn't make a difference. Meanwhile a colleague found that this is already confirmed as a bug in Chrome 34 by Google. Supposed to be fixed by mid May: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594

Comment: Wow! Just while I was writing my previous comment, my Chrome updated itself to 35, and the issue is fixed!

Answer (score 4):

It was a zoom issue for me on chrome.

Can you check your browser zoom? This is often an issue when the zoom puts the tiles at non-integer pixel coordinates. You can reset the zoom by hitting ctrl-0.

Comment: I am experiencing this in v3.x when browser zoomed in/out

Comment: I tried changing versions but i did not go away until this! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been confirmed on GMAP-API_Issue V3([here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594)).

Although widely reported as white lines issue, the color of these erroneous lines is the map's backgroundColor : selected on map option.

[btargac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3544243/btargac) solution worked for me.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this problem.  It seems to appear whenever a vertical scrollbar is displayed.  Tom's above answer removes the scrollbar, but that might not be a viable solution for most people.  This is most likely a Chrome bug.  They've made a lot of changes to the scrollbars over the past months, so this isn't surprising.

Comment: I have no scrollbar, but white lines.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I've come to the conclusion it is a Chrome bug. It's only shown up in the past week or so. It only occurs if you have a map centred. Here's how to reproduce the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html,body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;}
            #map-canvas { height: 600px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    zoom: 8
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                        mapOptions);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should see a centred map. If you resize your browser slowly the horizontal lines come and go.  If you remove the `margin:0 auto` from #map-canvas the map aligns left and the lines are gone.

Alternatively, add `max-width: 100%` to #map-canvas and you'll have a full width map and no lines. So, it's only centred maps which affects a lot of responsive sites.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the random horizontal white lines went away when I set the zoom level to an integer value (rather than a decimal value).