# Grey lines between tiles on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm having an issue where a thin grey line is appearing between the tiles on Google Maps. As far as I can tell it's just the tiles rendering a pixel too far over. It happens on some computers and not others. But it can usually be triggered just by using the browser's zoom.

Any ideas? My code is pretty standard I think:

```
var new_map

function init_new(){
    var new_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.874798,151.20698);
    var new_options = {
        center: new_latlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles : noPoi
    }
    new_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("new_map"), new_options);
    var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new_latlng,
        map: new_map,
        title: "My Marker"
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div id="content">Marker content</div>'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(new_map, new_marker);
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_new);
```

It outputs like this (in both Chrome and Firefox):

[image: grey lines]

Comment: Zooming can lead to pixel values getting rounded, which can sometimes lead to a certain "jitter" in element positions. No idea if this is the case here though.

Comment: I suspect you might be right @mensi but I'd like to get rid of it if I can.

Comment: Did you see any of the multiple questions concerning this (either caused by css issues or a bug in Chrome)?  Not sure if they apply to your case.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, it's happening in Firefox as well and I've looked over the CSS closely and there's no CSS causing the issue but if you've got any links I'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent issue with some of the google map apis based on version 3 running in Chrome. In my case, I had the exact same problem with version "3.exp"

Try this...

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&sensor=false"></script>
```

Which I originally found posted here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/23127040/3181867

And read up on here... https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594

Comment: Thanks @bluesky - I'm checking it.

Comment: since posting, I noticed that the line might occasionally appear through a marker. But it's not very obvious since its only the width of the marker and only happens on Chrome. Firefox is ok for me. Hope it helps you.