# Google Maps API v3.14 has gray line on markers

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have a gray line appearing in my google map through markers when I use version 3.14 of the api and when in Chrome.

Is there a fix for this ?

Saw this question but using the 3.14 version still has gray lines over the markers. The map tiles however are okay.
[Google Maps random vertical line in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997181/google-maps-random-vertical-line-in-chrome)

[image: Gray line runs through marker]